# How to make a realistic vertical and gorisontal swipe action in a protractor?

Tags: angularjs, appium

please help me, I can not do a scroll with a vertical and gorisontal swipe action
I tried so, example for vertical swipe, it doesn't work:

```
browser.actions ()
    .mouseDown (element (by.css ('. filter-editorial-rating .ngrs-handle-max')))
    .mouseMove ({x: 0, y: 50}) // value of Y how many pixels from above are shifted when scrolling
    .mouseUp ()
    .perform ();
```

It is necessary to scroll with the help of swipe, so that it looks like human action.

I also tried it

```
browser.controlFlow (). execute (function () {
    browser.executeScript ('arguments [0] .scrollIntoView ({behavior: "smooth"})',
    linkfound3.getWebElement ());
});
```

It's worked, but it just scrolling without imitate touching the screen

By the way, for example, the taps look like real actions, example:

```
browser.actions (). mouseMove (burger_link) .click (). perform ();
// it work as human
```

Maybe I should use vertical swipe through browser.actions, through taps, but I don’t know how to do it.

How to make a realistic swipe as human action in a protractor?
Please help or at least direct

**UPDATE:**

I found what I need! this is

```
    var startLocation = {
    x: 0,
    y: 50
    }
    var newLocation = {
    x: 0,
    y: 1000
    };


  browser.touchActions()
                 .tapAndHold(startLocation)
                 .move(newLocation)
                 .perform();
```

But the muve () function moves the cursor too fast. How to adjust the speed?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option

```
Var bottomPageEle = locator from bottom of the page.
```

Now to scroll vertical use the java script executor for using `scrollIntoView` option as below

```
await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", bottomPageEle);
await browser.sleep(3000);
```

The above js executor will perform the vertical scroll.

Hope it helps you

Comment: it doesn’t work the way I need, maybe I need to scroll through the tapes, do you know how to do this?

Comment: Did you try it out of `controlFlow`

Comment: I tried without controlFlow - this did not help. I came to the conclusion that for me it is scrolling a page using short-term vertical scrolling at different speeds, this will most likely look like a realistic user action. Maybe you know how to do this?

Comment: I found what I need! this is

        var startLocation = {
    x: 0,
    y: 50
  }
  var newLocation = {
    x: 0,
    y: 1000
  };

  
browser.touchActions()
                .tapAndHold(startLocation)
                .move(newLocation)
                .perform();


but the muve () function moves the cursor too fast. How to adjust the speed?